# Is giving "RESOURCE ERROR" when I clickd "profiles" page on Apache Drill webUI

Tags: apache-drill

I'm useing Apache Drill though webUI, but it's wrong when I clickd "profiles" page. Is giving the following error:

> "errorMessage" : "RESOURCE ERROR: Failed to get profiles from persistent or ephemeral store.\n\n\n[Error Id: 871b065f-031e-45c0-b17a-5cffab8aa3de ]"

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of Drill are you running?  What this looks like is a permission error.  The persistent stores are where Drill stores various bits that...well... persist.  So if those paths are not writable, the stores can't be created and thus you get an error.  Posting the complete error message would be helpful.